# Weblogic Web Services - EJB (not a jar) returns NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic, noclassdeffounderror

I am *very* new to development and have inherited a 10-year old application that was just converted from OAS to Weblogic. One of the operations of the web service does not work, while two do. When examining the source, it looks like the difference between the two that work and the one that does not is ejb-ref in the web.xml

The ear that is deployed is built with ant and there are no jar files within the ear file or it's war file. When the non-functioning operation is called with correct arguments from the weblogic web services testing page, it returns:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.geotools.cs.GeographicCoordinateSystem

- The ear file contains a /lib directory, a META-INF directory and a
  war file.
- The war file contains a classes directory, a META-INF
  directory and a number of xml documents.
- The library in question from
  the error exists in the /lib folder of the ear.

The application xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="5">
  <display-name>Map Viewer Services</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>MapViewerServicesPortTypeImpl.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>/outside/mapviewer</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

The weblogic-application.xml seems to contain only the default information:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<weblogic-application xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application/1.3/weblogic-application.xsd"></weblogic-application>
```

The /web/WEB-INF/web.xml contains the only reference to ejb:

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'windows-1252'?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>
  <description>web.xml file for Map Viewer Service Application</description>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>MapViewerWS</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>oracle.j2ee.ws.StatelessJavaRpcWebService</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>class-name</param-name>
      <param-value>ws1.mapViewer.MapViewerServices</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>interface-name</param-name>
      <param-value>ws1.mapViewer.IMapViewerWS</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MapViewerWS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MapViewerWS</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <session-config>
    <session-timeout>35</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>html</extension>
    <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <mime-mapping>
    <extension>txt</extension>
    <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
  </mime-mapping>
  <ejb-ref>
    <ejb-ref-name>ws1.mapViewer.NotifiedResults</ejb-ref-name>
    <ejb-ref-type>Session</ejb-ref-type>
    <home>ws1.mapViewer.NotifiedResultsHome</home>
    <remote>ws1.mapViewer.NotifiedResults</remote>
    <ejb-link>ws1.mapViewer.NotifiedResults</ejb-link>
  </ejb-ref>
</web-app>
```

If this is not sufficient information to be able to diagnose or suggest option, please let me know and I can post additional details. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Is the jar file for org.geotools.cs.GeographicCoordinateSystem in the lib folder? Also look into this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/programming/classloading.html